# Unity - Build failed with error

Tags: unity, build-process

I don't know how this happened but yesterday building just works fine for me until I tried it again and it gave me an error while building, I am using the same folder every time I build. (Builds Folder). Is there a way to resolve this?

Here are the errors that I got:

````
BuildFailedException: Burst compiler (1.1.1) failed running

stdout:
Burst requires Visual Studio (installable via Add Component in the Unity Installer) or the C++ build tools for Visual Studio, along with the Windows 10 SDK in order to build a standalone player for Windows with X86_SSE4
Failed to determine visual studio installation path - is Visual Studio installed?
stderr:

Unity.Burst.Editor.BurstAotCompiler+BclRunner.RunProgram (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.burst@1.1.1/Editor/BurstAotCompiler.cs:663)
Unity.Burst.Editor.BurstAotCompiler+BclRunner.RunManagedProgram (System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.burst@1.1.1/Editor/BurstAotCompiler.cs:601)
Unity.Burst.Editor.BurstAotCompiler+BclRunner.RunManagedProgram (System.String exe, System.String args, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.burst@1.1.1/Editor/BurstAotCompiler.cs:575)
Unity.Burst.Editor.BurstAotCompiler.OnPostBuildPlayerScriptDLLsImpl (UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.burst@1.1.1/Editor/BurstAotCompiler.cs:290)
Unity.Burst.Editor.BurstAotCompiler.OnPostBuildPlayerScriptDLLs (UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.burst@1.1.1/Editor/BurstAotCompiler.cs:46)
UnityEditor.Build.BuildPipelineInterfaces.OnPostBuildPlayerScriptDLLs (UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <7d90b28560b644ce87b8263efcc36eed>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)





BuildFailedException: Burst compiler (1.1.1) failed running

stdout:
Burst requires Visual Studio (installable via Add Component in the Unity Installer) or the C++ build tools for Visual Studio, along with the Windows 10 SDK in order to build a standalone player for Windows with X86_SSE4
Failed to determine visual studio installation path - is Visual Studio installed?
stderr:

Unity.Burst.Editor.BurstAotCompiler+BclRunner.RunProgram (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.burst@1.1.1/Editor/BurstAotCompiler.cs:663)
Unity.Burst.Editor.BurstAotCompiler+BclRunner.RunManagedProgram (System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.burst@1.1.1/Editor/BurstAotCompiler.cs:601)
Unity.Burst.Editor.BurstAotCompiler+BclRunner.RunManagedProgram (System.String exe, System.String args, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.burst@1.1.1/Editor/BurstAotCompiler.cs:575)
Unity.Burst.Editor.BurstAotCompiler.OnPostBuildPlayerScriptDLLsImpl (UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.burst@1.1.1/Editor/BurstAotCompiler.cs:290)
Unity.Burst.Editor.BurstAotCompiler.OnPostBuildPlayerScriptDLLs (UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.burst@1.1.1/Editor/BurstAotCompiler.cs:46)
UnityEditor.Build.BuildPipelineInterfaces.OnPostBuildPlayerScriptDLLs (UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <7d90b28560b644ce87b8263efcc36eed>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)





Error building Player: BuildFailedException: Burst compiler (1.1.1) failed running

stdout:
Burst requires Visual Studio (installable via Add Component in the Unity Installer) or the C++ build tools for Visual Studio, along with the Windows 10 SDK in order to build a standalone player for Windows with X86_SSE4
Failed to determine visual studio installation path - is Visual Studio installed?
stderr:





Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 17 seconds (17004 ms)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)





UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 4 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002bb] in <7d90b28560b644ce87b8263efcc36eed>:0 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in <7d90b28560b644ce87b8263efcc36eed>:0 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```
````

Comment: Did you check what the build log tells you to check? Has a Windows updated occured overnight?

Comment: Looks like Unity is having trouble finding its dependencies. It might be wise to try uninstalling and re-installing Unity and Visual Studio, clearing your package cache and re-installing the packages you need, to see if that solves it.

Comment: I think there's a problem in my project, I tried building another project and it worked.

Comment: If you can copy content from your broken project to your working project incrementally, building after each addition, that should help you track down the specific piece of content or setup that's causing this issue, and use that information to get more focused answers.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are missing some crucial resources in order to compile. Here are the resources necessary I found in the error codes:

1. You need **Visual Studio** and/or the C++ build tools for Visual Studio (required for Burst to compile)
2. **Windows 10 SDK**

Those are all the requirements I could find in the log.

Answer (score 1):

[image]Did you add any packages that had dependencies on the Burst Compiler, as I added a Animation Rigger and forgot the compiler and got exact same message.
Try looking at dependencies listed on package in Unity > Package Manager > PACKAGE
Good luck.